# R coding: method to obtain the interaction of fixed effects and extract in latex

Tags: r, fixed, effect, interaction

I am working with panel data and using the 'lm' function to solve for the *interaction* of fixed effects.  The summary feature shows all effects which is good for my knowledge but I only need to extract a summary that concisely shows the *aggregate* effect of this fixed interaction.

Ideally, I would like to see the significance of the covariates alongside all fixed effects in a concise summary table that I can export with stargazer (or another tool) to latex.

See below for example code:

```
company<-c("aapl", "ba", "ko",  "csco", "dis", "xom", "ge", "ibm", "aapl", "ba", "intc", "cvx", "cat" )  

year <-c("1984","1984","1984","1984", "1985", "1985","1986", "1987","1989","1989","1990","1990","1990" )

sic <-c("53","53","58","58", "60", "60","60", "60","53", "53","22","22","22")

inv <- rnorm(13,0,10)  
rev <- rnorm(13,0,10)  
asset <- rnorm(13,0,10)  
cash  <- rnorm(13,0,10)  

#Show dataframe  
fe.data <-data.frame( year, sic, company, inv, rev, asset, cash )
```

The factor variable 'sic' represents an industry id. What I am looking to *effect-out* of my model is the year-sic fixed effect interaction as it might be correlated with a primary covariate in my regression.

Here's a proxy of my current lm model:

```
lm.fe <- lm(inv ~ rev + asset + cash  + factor(year:sic)-1, data = fe.data)

summary(lm.fe)
```

You will notice in the summary (seven) year:sic interactions along with std error, significance etc.

My actual model is much larger than this, with other individual and combined fixed effects with various covariates, so it is rather unwieldy to export/analyze.

Looking for a better way to approach this, either with a more efficient/relevant modeling package or perhaps via consolidation of the current output.

Thank you so much for your help~ MD